# I have a house plant no one has been able to identify,

Tags: houseplants

I have a house plant that has grown tall (3'), It has a single stem with large elliptical green leaves.  On the perimeter of these leaves are what looks like round green seed pods about the size of a small pea with probably 20-30 pods on the perimeter edge of each leaf.  The color of the plant is a light green.  The plant seems to be very hardy.  I keep it indoors where it gets lots of odd looks.  I really don't know if this is an outdoor or indoor plant.  The seed pods that have fallen off the leaves into the pot below have sprouted and are growing so this plant seems to reproduce easily.  Any help in identifying this plant would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a photo, but perhaps [_Bryophyllum pinnatum_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryophyllum_pinnatum) or [_B. daigremontianum_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryophyllum_daigremontianum)?

Comment: here are some pictures of Niall's suggestion https://www.google.ca/search?q=plant+mother+of+thousands&rlz=1C1CHFX_enCA540CA540&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=67r6UrmIDYfKsQSLpYGwBw&ved=0CCgQsAQ&biw=1137&bih=527&dpr=0.9

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.

Answer (score 1):

From the description, it sounds like a [*Bryophyllum daigremontianum*, or Mexican Hat Plant.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryophyllum_daigremontianum) This is a common succulent house plant, and the sprouts along the leaf edges are a special reproductive adaptation, as you've noted. Water it sparingly, and keep it in a sunny spot. As you've also noted, this is a resilient plant. It won't need much care if you supply the basics.